# How to embed image in liferay email?

Tags: email, liferay-6, email-attachments, liferay-7

we have a requirement where we need to embed an image in email instead of hosting it on any server and refer its link in anchor.

I have come across the "Contend-id" concept in message header and then refer the image in anchor with content id. It seems to be working in java mail api. However i would like to do the same with MailMessage of liferay.

But there is no option to set content header in MailMessage bean of java.

is there any way to achieve this?
we don't want to host image on any server it has to be embedded in email like attachment.

Comment: Have you tried using base64 encoded images?

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.liferay.mail.kernel.service.MailServiceUtil;


public void sendMailWithAttachment() {


    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content- handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");

    try {


        Transport transport = MailServiceUtil.getSession().getTransport();

        Message message = new MimeMessage(MailServiceUtil.getSession());
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no-reply@test.com"));
        message.setSubject("send email with Java");
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("joe@test.com"));

        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        String htmlText = "<H1>Hello</H1><img src=\"cid:image\">";
        messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource fds = new FileDataSource
                ("D:\\temp\\image\\newJob.jpg");
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // put everything together
        message.setContent(multipart);
        transport.connect();
        transport.sendMessage(message,
                message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();

        System.out.println("Send mail using Java ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
}
```